# Hook drag and drop of Windows Explorer with C#?

Tags: c#

I want to write an application in C# that only opens when the user starts to drag a file in the Windows Explorer. It doesn't matter if the file will be dropped in the app, i only want to know whenever the user drags a file in explorer, and of course, when he releases it again.

I found this article, but I don't really know where to start: [Detect drag and drop operations in an external application using .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746380/detect-drag-and-drop-operations-in-an-external-application-using-net)

Since I know hardly anything about hooking, I would really appreciate it if someone could give me an example of doing that, or some ideas.

Comment: That's not how this site works - you have to write the code :) We can (only) help if you have a specific problem within your own attempt at a solution.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes i know how this site works, but what should I do when I have no begging? I've been searching the whole day now about how i could do this, and my last option is always this. If you know something please help me :(

Comment: This might point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781948/how-can-i-hook-globaly-all-the-keys-and-all-the-mouse-buttons